# Help with making a large print - 60 x 36 - will my photo work?

Tags: digital, printing

I would like to make a very large print of a photo I have taken, of about 60 inches wide, and about 36 inches high (though the actual aspect ratio of the cropped file would imply a 34 in height).

The size of the image is 4858x2733 pixels.  Is it possible to make a print of that size and have it look okay without additional post processing?  What's the largest print I could comfortably make without printing on canvas?

Thanks so much,
Tom

Comment: see: [is there a general formula for image size vs print size](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/456/is-there-a-general-formula-for-image-size-vs-print-size)

Comment: The comments to the answer to this question are very relevant to the question here: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16626/what-resolution-would-be-needed-for-a-billboard-advertisement/16627#16627

Answer (score 0):

For *close viewing* (but not fine art quality), ~300 dpi suffice, which would give a maximum size ~16 x 10 in. For a poster to be viewed from a distance, though, coarse pixelization may be acceptable. It was to the Pointillists... and [Roy Lichtenstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roy_Lichtenstein) took it to the digital extreme.