# Size of printed photo

Tags: megapixels

I have a nikon d3100 , A friend of mine needs a headshot for a billboard.I need to know if my camera can take a pic big enough (mp)
I do have a 50mm lens I can use and plan to use a tripod and plan on using RAW.

Comment: related - https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/how-do-i-generate-high-quality-prints-with-an-ink-jet-printer & https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/456/is-there-a-general-formula-for-image-size-vs-print-size

Comment: Related: [What resolution would be needed for a billboard advertisement?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/16626/15871)

Answer (score 4):

Billboards are often printed with an apparently ridiculously low resolution if you only consider their absolute size. If you however also think about the typical viewing distance and how small they appear at that distance, it all makes sense. The resolution of a typical human eye is not high enough to make it necessary to print billboards in a higher quality.

Here is a recent YouTube video with a more precise look at an actual billboard. According to that video, 2MP seems to be enough and it actually sounds reasonable: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCaZt5ndRW0

So if you only count pixels, you would cope with a 15 year old camera from the dawn of the digital photography era, the cheapest possible lens, forget the tripod and use highly compressed JPEG. There is however much more behind decent marketing photography than just the technical parameters of the equipment. Do *you* as a photographer have what it takes to make a highbrow presentation of your friend by taking care of composition, posture and lighting of the image?